# PandasのDataframeにあるデータを対象に分位数を使った足切りをしたい

Tags: python, python3, pandas

### 概要

PandasのDataframeにあるデータを、列のラベルごとに集計し、特定の分位数を使って外れ値の除外をするにはどのようなコードを書けばよいでしょうか?

### 詳細

環境はpython3.6です
対象となるDataframeは以下のような内容です

```
sensor_name temperature Humidity Pressure
sensor1 15.5 67 1001
sensor1 15.8 68 1009
sensor2 13.3 57 1009
sensor2 13.2 55 1008
...
```

このようなDataframe(dataと命名)に対して、以下のコードである定数の分位数を求めました

```
data_q = data.grpupby("sensor_name").quantile(0.9)
```

こうすることで以下のようなDataframe(data_qと命名)を得られました

```
sensor_name temperature Humidity Pressure
sensor1 18.8 75 1014
sensor2 14.5 66 1015
sensor3 15.5 87 1002
...
```

この二つのDataframeを使って、dataに含まれている分位数(サンプルコードでは90%)より大きな値はNaNとするコードはどのようなコードになりますでしょうか?
理想の結果は以下のような内容となります

```
sensor_name temperature Humidity Pressure
sensor1 99.9 70 1004
↓
sensor1の気温データがdata_qにあるsensor1の気温データを超過するためNaNを代入
sensor_name temperature Humidity Pressure
sensor1 NaN 70 1004
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こちらの記事のように[pandas.DataFrame.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)あるいは[pandas.DataFrame.mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html)を使用すれば良いでしょう。
[pandasで条件に応じて値を代入（where, mask）](https://note.nkmk.me/python-pandas-where-mask/)

以下のようにしてnumpyもimportしておきます。

```
import numpy as np
```

whereを使う場合はこちらになります。

```
data_q['temperature'].where(data_q['temperature'] <= 90.0, np.nan, inplace=True)
```

maskを使う場合はこちらになります。

```
data_q['temperature'].mask(data_q['temperature'] > 90.0, np.nan, inplace=True)
```

python 3.10で確認したのでpython 3.6では変わるかもしれませんが、試してみてください。